# Drupal 7 quantity of content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 website with a content type for each product type. In the past I have incorporated sizes (XS,S,M,L,XL) with term reference into one of the product types (the other are size independent).
I would like to have stock information available now too (without using Drupal Commerce).
I could add an integer field to the content types for this. But the products that are size dependant should have stock info for each size.
One important thing it that it should be easy to manage the content types with their stock information with drupal feeds

Does anyone have an idea for achieving this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the [Field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to make a field collection that contains a size field, and stock levels field. This would be attached to a product, so each product can have multiple sizes, and each size has a stock level.

Comment: I was looking at that module as we speak. Any experience in combination with feeds module? Would it work?

Comment: No, I have no experience of using those 2 modules together myself but see [Field collection feeds](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_feeds)

Comment: aha there is a plugin to the feeds module for it. I'll have a go at it, will report back with my findings

Comment: This wil work i think. The only drawback is that I need a separate feed for the content type and the stock information